# Jenkins Maven 3 build does not pick up the latest version matching version range

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-3

We have project A that builds into a jar file and project B that includes a dependency on project A. Somehow when Jenkins builds project B it doesn't always pick the latest version of project A even though it's within the version range.

For example I just did the build on Project B and even though the latest version of project A is projectA-1.0.20160425-2125.54.jar it picked up the earlier version which is core-1.0.20160422-1926.49.jar.

How could this be resolved so that Project B always picks up the latest Project A build within the range?

**Here are more details...**

In Jenkins, Project A is built using this Maven3 line:

```
clean pmd:pmd deploy -P buildServer -DversionMajor=1 -DversionMinor=0 -DbuildNumber=$BUILD_NUMBER
```

In Jenkins, Project B is built using this Maven3 line:

```
clean pmd:pmd deploy generate-sources javadoc:jar source:jar -DversionMajor=7 -DversionMinor=0 -DbuildNumber=$BUILD_NUMBER
```

Here are excerpts from pom.xml files for both projects...

Project A:

```
<groupId>vod</groupId>
<artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
<version>${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${maven.build.timestamp}.${buildNumber}</version>
```

Project B:

```
<groupId>vod</groupId>
<artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
<version>${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${maven.build.timestamp}.${buildNum
<dependency>
    <groupId>vod</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>[1.0,2.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use -SNAPSHOT classifier when defining version, this is a standard maven mechanism. That is:

Define project A version as 1.2-SNAPSHOT, that way the world SNAPSHOT will be automatically replaced by a timestamp at build time.

Then on project B reference A with 1.2-SNAPSHOT, that way maven will automatically picked the A build with the greatest timestamp. I recommend to take a look at this short article about SNAPSHOTs: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_snapshots.htm

Comment: NicoPaez, Thank you for your answer. Were you going to attach a link to the article you referred to?

Comment: oops! I have just added the link. Thanks!